# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx = 0$ implies $f_n \to f$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

If $f_n,f$ are Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx = 0$, then is it true that $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[a,b]$?

Comment: As answered below by user284331 this is not true, however there is pointwise convegence almost every where. More precisely for all $\epsilon>0$, you can find a sequence of intervals whose length sum up to less than $\epsilon$ containing all the "bad" points in which you don't have pointwise convegence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $f_{n}(0)=1$ and $f_{n}(x)=0$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $f=0$.